# Add data to specific cells in a column

Tags: excel, vba

The below code copies from one file to another.
I only want TO ADD the word "AVA" to cells in the Column H but only until the last row.
So basically the macro filters on "PENDING" and I have 14 rows of Pending data , then all the  14 cells of Column H should be showing "AVA".

Any recommendations?

```
Sub DS()

    Dim sourceWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet

    Dim sourceWorkbookPath As String
    Dim targetWorkbookPath As String
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long


    ' Define workbooks paths
    sourceWorkbookPath = "H:\Roy\Transfers Project\ Transfers 2020 - Roy.xlsm"
    targetWorkbookPath = "H:\Roy\ 2020\SAP - ZPSD02_template2.xlsx"

    ' Set a reference to the target Workbook and sheets
    Set sourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(sourceWorkbookPath)
    Set targetWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(targetWorkbookPath)

    ' definr worksheet's names for each workbook
    Set sourceSheet = sourceWorkbook.Worksheets("S TO S")
    Set targetSheet = targetWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With sourceSheet

        ' Get last row
        lastRow = .Range("J" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To lastRow
        .Range("H" & i).Value = "AVA" & .Range("H" & i).Value
    Next i

        .Range("A1:O1").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="PENDING"
        .Range("A1:O1").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="U3R", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="U2R"

        .Range("J2:J" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                                     Destination:=targetSheet.Range("A1")
        .Range("C2:C" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                                     Destination:=targetSheet.Range("B1")
        .Range("D2:D" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                                     Destination:=targetSheet.Range("E1")
        .Range("H2:H" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                                     Destination:=targetSheet.Range("F1")
    End With


    With targetSheet
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        .Range("H" & i).Value = "AVA"
    Next i
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: If you were trying my answer, I have just rethought it and updated it to be much cleaner.

Comment: Hi @RicardoDiaz

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub DS()

    Dim sourceWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet

    Dim sourceWorkbookPath As String
    Dim targetWorkbookPath As String
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' Define workbooks paths
    sourceWorkbookPath = "H:\Roy\Transfers Project\ Transfers 2020 - Roy.xlsm"
    targetWorkbookPath = "H:\Roy\ 2020\SAP - ZPSD02_template2.xlsx"

    ' Set a reference to the target Workbook and sheets
    Set sourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(sourceWorkbookPath)
    Set targetWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(targetWorkbookPath)

    ' Define worksheet's names for each workbook
    Set sourceSheet = sourceWorkbook.Worksheets("S TO S")
    Set targetSheet = targetWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With sourceSheet
        ' Get last row
        lastRow = .Range("J" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        .Range("A1:O1").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="PENDING"
        .Range("A1:O1").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="U3R", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="U2R"

        .Range("J2:J" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=targetSheet.Range("A1")
        .Range("C2:C" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=targetSheet.Range("B1")
        .Range("D2:D" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=targetSheet.Range("E1")
        .Range("H2:H" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=targetSheet.Range("F1")
    End With


    With targetSheet
        For i = 1 To lastRow
            .Range("H" & i).Value = "AVA"
        Next i
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Mech Thanks for the help!  I added this to my code and my excel hangs up. I just want "AVA" in the destination Column H until the row that has data.

Comment: NP. Give that version a try :) I've added application.screenupdating to help with the hanging up issue.

Comment: Hi @Mech  It still hangs up. Do you know why? Didn't happen earlier. Let me edit my code so that you can see the whole code.

Comment: Thanks for the complete code. It looks like you left the original addition in that was causing the original hang up. If this doesn't work for you, can you let me know what lastRow yields when you run the macro? You can debug.print, msgbox, or use F8 to go through the code step by step and hover over the variable name to get the value.

Comment: Hi @Mech I tried both , debug and F8 , but as soon as my code reaches that it starts running. I removed everything and restored my original code and it works. I'm open to removing the "With" Code as long as the output is the same. Thanks for continued help!

Comment: Can you try adding `lastRow = 10` below `lastRow = .Range("J" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` and see how it runs?

Comment: Hi @Mech I tried and it gives me Run time error '9' Subscript out of Range   Range("J2:J" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                                     Destination:=targetSheet.Range("A1")

Comment: Comment out your filters too then try.